# Running a laravel 9 project cloned from github

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have cloned a laravel 9 project which is working in the System it created.
The laravel project uses sail to run the project in PHP 8. I am not able to run the local version in the system where I cloned the project.
I tried the following code as per the documentation

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This gives an error telling a composer.json is not found

I have then tried docker compose up

and it fails at the first building phase

My PHP version is 7.4 but I need PHP 8 in the container to run laravel 9

Can anyone explain how I can run git cloned dockerized laravel 9

Comment: i added an answer, it could be nice if you can share the git repo URI

Answer (score 0):

double check if composer.json is there it must be since it contains all the configuration packages, dependencies, etc.
Once you find it run the following commands on the
terminal:

1. composer install
2. composer update -o --optimize-autoloader
3. composer dump-autoload -o --optimize

Be sure to not get any dependency error and/or version conflicts and finally run:

php artisan serve, so the app runs in localhost:8000